# What book is best to learn order statistics?

Tags: references, order-statistics

PhD in Physics here doing some theory that has to do with order statistics. I've never had a formal introduction to a lot of probability theory and think I would greatly benefit from it. Any good recommendations for someone looking for a formal introduction to order statistics of independent random variables?

Comment: Look for books by N. Balakrishnan.

Comment: Do you have a favorite that also covers order stats?

Comment: You can also look at the book by H. A. David.

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe start with "A First Course in Order Statistics" by Arnold & Balakrishnan & Nagaraja, in the series Siam Classics in Applied Mathematics.

There is also from Wiley "Order Statistics" by David & Nagaraja, which have much of the same information.

Then there is a more advanced book with newer results, "Approximate Distributions
of Order Statistics
With Applications to Nonparametric
Statistics" by  R.-D. Reiss  (Springer).